# Proving $f(u) = \lambda u \iff f(\bar u) = \bar \lambda \bar u$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm having trouble understand the following proposition:

> Let $f: \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n$ be an endomorphism and let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $f$, then:
>
> 1. $\bar \lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $f$
> 2. $f(u) = \lambda u \iff f(\bar u) = \bar \lambda \bar u$

If $p$ is the characteristic polynomial of $f$ then if $\lambda$ is a root, $\bar \lambda$ is also a root, that I understand. What I don't understand is proposition number (2). Why is that true?

Comment: When you write "endomorphism", what structure are you looking at? Viewing it as a $\Bbb C$-vector space does not give you the results you're hoping for.

Comment: "If $p$ is a polynomial and $z$ is a root then $\bar z$ is also a root" only applies when the coefficients of $p$ are real? @AryamanMaithani

Comment: Yes, otherwise it may not be true. Consider $p(z) = z - i$ for example.

Comment: $\mathbb C ^n$ over the field $\mathbb C$ @AryamanMaithani

Comment: Then your claims are false.

Comment: We know that $p$ is base invariant, so we could choose a basis for $\mathbb C^n$ such that the matrix of $f$ only has real entries, right? @AryamanMaithani

Comment: No, you cannot always choose that.

Comment: Let's that, for example, the matrix of $f$ in relation to the canonical basis only has real entries, then would this be true? @AryamanMaithani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: let  $A= diag (0,i)$

(a $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrix)

and $f(u):=Au$ for $u \in \mathbb C^2$.

The eigenvalues auf $f$ are $0$ and $i$. But $ \bar i =-i$ is not an eigenvalue of $f$.

Comment: Yeah that's true, Then what conditions do we need so that this proposition is true?

Comment: Let's that, for example, the matrix of $f$ in relation to the canonical basis only has real entries, is this true?